# https not workking AWS ELB(ssl cert) + FLASK + NGNIX

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS Load balancer with SSL which is pointing to a ec2(windows) on 80, i.e on LB,
https 443 http 80
However the app i'm running is on another port 9100 which is configured in ngnix, now i'm unable to access the server via https

Please help me out on this

here is my nginx config,

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9100;
            proxy_connect_timeout 150;
            proxy_send_timeout 100;
            proxy_read_timeout 100;
            proxy_buffers 4 32k;
            client_max_body_size 8m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        }
}
```

Comment: Change port 80 to 9100

Comment: If you have set the ELB to use none-ssl (http) in it's connection to port 80 on the EC2 instance, then there is no SSL to handle in Flask, it's already been taken care of by the ELB. Perhaps you could clarify the question?

Comment: @hjpotter92 i have already added the port 9100 as proxy_pass in nginx. However the https is not working where as http is working

Comment: @SteveE. I configured the port 9100 in nginx for https, here is my nginx config-

Comment: @IAmHomes Why do you need nginx proxy, if you already are using a load balancer?

Comment: @hjpotter92 because i'm using same instance for multiple applications on port 80

Comment: As everybody is trying to point out. When using ELB with an SSL cert you do not need to configure SSL on your webserver (Nginx).

Comment: @GeorgeMWhitaker But George the https link is not working, so i'm getting confused

Comment: An observation. Your Nginx config will not talk SSL to port 9100. Because the proxy pass directive in your question is using http: instead of https:. If the proxy_pass is failing there should be an error message in the nginx logs. What is it?

Comment: Your ELB should have port 443 pointed to port 80 or 9100. Which ever one is working without SSL.  Make sure you have the ELB setup with a SSL cert and the domain that matches the cert pointed at your ELB.

Comment: @SteveE. SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL

Comment: @GeorgeMWhitaker it is pointed to 80 and the ssl is matching to the domain

Comment: @IAmHomes, OK, that's helpful. Are you sure https is correctly configured in Flask (With Import SSL....)? A quick test from the EC2 instance with curl may help 'curl -k https://127.0.0.1:9100'. Do you get a similar error message?

Comment: @SteveE. i didn't import any ssl in flask, it runs on http

Comment: Your question says 'now my question is how to handle the ssl in flask'?

Comment: @SteveE. my bad, i was confused on where to write the code(Nginx or flask) so that the https will work

Answer (score 0):

There  are many examples of Nginx with https around. Merging the [Nginx HTTPS](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) documentation with your sample configuration gives something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9100;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }
}
```

This will get Nginx to serve traffic as HTTPS on port 443. You would need to update the ELB to send HTTPS traffic to port 443 if it's coming via that device.

You would also need to update the Nginx ssl_certificate & ssl_certificate_key options to point to somewhere on the EC2 instance that contains those files.

Comment: i have the ssl key on AWS Cert manager linked to the elb port(443), so now is there anyway that i can skip that here or is it a must?

Comment: AFAIK, if you created the Initial Certificate Signing Request (CSR) in AWS then you cannot download the private key and therefore cannot use it with Nginx. But you can terminate SSL on the ELB and forward the http traffic onto Nginx.

Comment: I think i got hold of this, thanks for your help guys